# python: builtin function redefinition, with different arguments

Tags: python, built-in, monkeypatching

Preface: the question is to understand python internals, so pls don't answer with 'upgrade python' or 'import six'

Let take for example, 'print'

To replace the 'print' builtin, I can write my python function.

python 2.6 : at runtime, I get **syntax error**

solution

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now I can redefine print.
Why ?
I think because now my print declaration is the same as the new print function.

python 2.4 : at runtime, I get **syntax error**

There isn't

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

So, for `print` (or any other builtin): is it possible to monkey patch with a new function, with a different declaration - args and kwargs ?

---

In other words.

`from __future__ import print_function` substitutes the keyword with a function. I want to understand HOW, in general. Please don't be focused exclusively on `print`, it is an handy example.

Comment: In Python 2, `print` was a keyword you could not assign to. In Python 3, `print` is "just" a function which a name you can reassign. `__future__` imports are a little bit of magic.

Comment: not a pro here, but `from future import print` tellls the interpreter to load a python 3 stlye `print function` - for python 2x print was not a function but a protected keyword that is protected from being redefined

Comment: Side-note: The docs claim `from __future__ import print_function` [was new in 2.6.0a2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), so it's a little strange that it works in 2.5...

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thnks, you're right, I confuse with 'with_statement'. My question still stands.

Comment: You say "Please don't be focused exclusively on `print`, it is an handy example." but there is literally nothing else remotely like the case of `print` on Python 2. In no other scenario does a `__future__` import change a keyword to a non-reserved word (some imports change non-reserved words to keywords, but `print_function` is the only case going from keyword to non-keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `from __future__ import print_function` does is toggle a flag in the parser to make it stop treating `print` as a keyword; once that's done, references to `print` seamlessly become like references to any other non-keyword that constitutes a legal variable name (they go through LEGB lookup, and get found in the B of LEGB, the builtins scope). This behavior is hard-coded deep in the Python interpreter; there is no way to achieve a similar effect for any other keyword without building a custom version of Python, or engaging in some other egregious hackery well beyond the scope of any reasonable problem.

As of 2.6, `__builtin__` has a `print` function on it, so any module that uses `from __future__ import print_function` (and can therefore reference the *name* `print` as opposed to the *keyword* `print`) will see `__builtin__.print` (if it hasn't been shadowed by something in the local, nested or global scope). It's still *there* for *every* module, but in modules without the `__future__` import, references to `print` are resolved to the keyword at compile time and replaced with the raw bytecode implementing the special `print` *statement* (the same way `del` and `return` behave; you can't name a variable either of those things for the same reason, they're keywords), so modules without the import never get a chance to lookup the `print` *function*.

This doesn't generalize to other cases, because `__future__` has no other cases where one of its features converts a keyword to a non-keyword. For all other actual built-in functions, being able to overwrite them on a per-module basis is as simple as assigning to the name at global scope (shadowing it for that module), e.g.:

```
def abs(x):
    return x  # Who needs absolute value anyway?
# From here on out, references to abs in this module see your override, not the built-in
```

While it's possible to reassign the built-in globally, it's a terrible idea (since every other module that uses it likely relies on the built-ins original behavior). That said, it's not hard:

```
import __builtin__

def abs(x):
    return x  # Who needs absolute value anyway?

__builtin__.abs = abs
# *Every* module now sees your terrible monkeypatch, on your own head be it
```

Comment: @user2357112: That edit wasn't actually necessary; `__builtins__` (with `s`) is a weird auto-imported CPython implementation detail that provides the same attributes as the official (but not auto-imported) `__builtin__` (without `s`) provides. I'll grant the distinction is confusing, so it doesn't hurt anything to use `__builtin__` consistently.

Comment: The behavior of `__builtins__` in a module is subtly different from its behavior in interactive mode; specifically, inside a module, `__builtins__` will usually be the `__builtin__` module's `__dict__` rather than the module itself. Using `__builtin__`/`builtins` instead of `__builtins__` avoids this quirk.

Comment: @user2357112: True. Forgot about that bit of weirdness. I withdraw my (extremely minor) objection. :-)

Comment: I take the *print* example... and it is a special case, sigh! Now it is clear why on old python 2.x I cannot patch it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `print` is a keyword. You can't redefine `print` for the same reason you can't redefine `if`, `while`, `def`, or any other language keyword; they're part of the language syntax, and they're handled by the parser, not by looking up a function.

`from __future__ import print_function` is also handled by the parser. It looks like a normal import, and it does actually import a thing, but the thing it imports has nothing to do with the statement's primary functionality, which is to tell the parser to stop treating `print` as a keyword.

With the keyword disabled, `print` is treated as an ordinary name following ordinary name lookup rules. Such a lookup finds the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) built-in function, which is normally hidden by the keyword.

You cannot define your own magic imports; they have to be built into the interpreter itself. Since you cannot define your own magic imports, and since no other `__future__` imports turn keywords into non-keywords, there's no generalization to be done.

(People will sometimes say that builtins like `list` or `dict` are keywords. They're not keywords; those people are using the word "keyword" incorrectly.)

---

As for monkey-patching built-in functions (not keywords) with a different signature from the original, you can do that. It's probably a bad idea, but you can do it. The process is identical to how you'd monkey-patch a built-in normally.

Comment: Amusing implementation detail: Once `from __future__ import print_function` is available, even when it's not activated, `print` *is* a builtin (you can access it with `vars(__builtins__)['print']`). It's just that unless the future feature is active, `print` being a keyword takes effect before LEGB lookup, so you never try to look up the name `print` unless you're using weird hacks to pull it from the builtins by string name.

Comment: 'from __future__ import print_function' substitutes the keyword with a function. I want to understand HOW, in general. pls don't be focused exclusively on print, it is an handy example.

Comment: @Massimo: The case of `from __future__ import print_function` is unique; no other built-in requires that sort of rigmarole, because `print` is unique in that, on Py2, it defaults to being a keyword statement, like `del`, `return`, etc., not a function at all. That's why you can't normally replace it. Everything else is either always a keyword statement (can never be replaced) or always a built-in function (can always be replaced, though it's often a bad idea).

Comment: But it's not general.  It's a specific hack in the parser that turns off the keyword.  There is no general version of it.

Comment: `from __future__ import ...`, despite sharing the same syntax, is *not* a regular import. It fundamentally alters the language recognized by the parser (which is why it *must* be the first statement in a module). Note that `getattr(__builtins__, 'print')("hi")` works without the `__future__` import.